# Is it possible to insert an array as a row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
create table mytable(id text, name text, phone text)
```

and arrays

```
ARRAY['1','Billy','123'] ARRAY['2','Ann','321'] ARRAY['3','Ivor','213']
```

I want to get the result as below

```
 id|name |phone 
---+-----+------
 1 |Billy|123
 2 |Ann  |321
```

I tried to do this

```
insert into (id, name, phone)
select * from 
unnest('{1,Billy,123}'::TEXT[],'{2,Ann,321}'::TEXT[],'{3,Ivor,213}'::TEXT[])
```

But I got the wrong result

```
 id    |name   |phone
-------+-------+------
 1     |2      |3
 Billy |Ann    |Ivor
 123   |321    |213
```

Is it possible to insert an array as a row or is it possible to insert only as a column?

Comment: Why not use the standard VALUES syntax? `insert into ... values (1, 'Billy', 123), (2, 'Ann', 321), ...;`?

Comment: You can use something like `SELECT ('(' || array_to_string(ARRAY['1','Billy','123'],',') || ')')::mytable`, but that won't work if any of the values contains a comma. It is a rather unusual requirement.

Comment: if you have the possiblity to add column names  in your input, you could use `select * from jsonb_populate_recordset(null::mytable, to_jsonb(array['{"id": 1, "name": 2}'::jsonb, '{"id": 3, "name": 4}'::jsonb]));`

Answer (score 1):

This could solve your case

```sql
insert into mytable(id, name, phone)
select a[1], a[2], a[3] 
from 
(
 values (array['1','billy','123']),(array['2','ann','321']),(array['3','ivor','213'])
) as t(a);
```

or the equivalent

```sql
insert into mytable(id, name, phone)
select a[1], a[2], a[3] 
from 
(
 values
 ('{1,billy,123}'::text[]),('{2,ann,321}'),('{3,ivor,213}')
) as t(a);
```